# Need IE 8 Solution for ellipsis and image

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-8, ellipsis

I've seen a lot of similar issues, but nothing exactly like this.  I need to float an image to the right of some text that ellipsises if too long.

A.) This needs to work in IE 8 (standards mode).  No other browser requirement.

B.) The image needs to be immediately to the right of the text, and the image cannot be cut off when the ellipsis starts.

C.) The image cannot move to the next line.

D.) I'm not sure if using a table really works, since it won't really scale to different screen resolutions.

Here's a semi-broken example:  https://jsfiddle.net/q7p4nf6t/1/

The really long text is somewhat working, the short text is not.  The real crux of the issue is that I can't get ellipsis to work without a width on the text div; and I really don't want a width on the text div since I want the image to sit right next to the text.  And don't forget I need this to work in IE 8, and IE 8 only...

The HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">
  Some short text
  </div>
  <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded&a">
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="text">
  Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text
  </div>
  <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded&a">
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.container{
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.text{
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  width:95%;
  display:inline-block;
}

img{
  height:20px;
  width:20px;
  display:inline;
}
```

Comment: Is it helpful for you? https://jsfiddle.net/q7p4nf6t/3/ Use `max-width` instead of `width`

Comment: @MuhammadUsman Amazing, that works !!!!  THANKS A MILLION!